# Create two buttons overlapping a DIV

Tags: html, css

I would like two create two buttons that overlay a div using HTML like  the following:

[image]

*Both the same DIV with two buttons overlapping each side. So one div with two buttons overlapping.

I would like the buttons to be transparent and overlay the div but I am not sure how.

I have created my Div:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">

    </div>
  </div>
```

The div I would like to overlay is called "container" and the two buttons are:

```
 <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
```

Is there any way in CSS or HTML to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Great to see new 'recruits' for our noble profession! I've seen worse questions, but for a next time, please experiment away, and show what you have tried, even if it didn't work as expected. That said, if the buttons/links are inside the container div, it's relatively easy to position them (`position: relative` on the container, and `position: absolute` with some width/height/top/left on the buttons). If not, it's way harder and you may need JavaScript. Can you show where the buttons are in the HTML structure?

Comment: The buttons are inside the div sir

Comment: So, you are trying to create an image carousel with two buttons to navigate `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to place your buttons absolutely on top of your image. To do so, first make `.container` take a `position: relative;` and then put your buttons as siblings of your `.slides` div and place them absolutely.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.slidesjs-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* Added in case you want to transition this */
}

.slidesjs-navigation:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25); /* Makes the hovered button visible */
}

.slidesjs-previous {
  left: 0;
}

.slidesjs-next {
  right: 0; /* left: 50%; works too */
}

.slides img {
  display: block; /* Avoids the space usually seen under inline images */
  width: 100%; /* Ensures the image takes up the whole width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="slides" class="slides">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4147/5087404401_d24513119a_b.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/"><!-- original `src`: "img/example-slide-1.jpg" -->
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it. Put both buttons inside a div with a `height:100%`, `width:50%` and `float:left;`. This way each button takes up the full height of the div but only half of its width. The `float:left;` will then put them side by side in the div, hopefully achieving what you want!

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:#005680;
}

.button1 {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border:0px solid black;
}

.button2 {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border:0px solid black;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.1);
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button class="button1"></button>
  <button class="button2"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: But will not 'cover' the div as such. Since the div has other content too, this will not work properly.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

So basically you would like to create something similar to a toggle button or on/off switch? You could try something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle">
    <a id="left-side" href="">Left</a>
    <a id="right-side" href="">Right</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<script type="text/css">
    DIV#toggle { 
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    DIV#toggle>A {
        display:block;
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0px;
        text-size:10pt;
        text-align:center; 
    }
    DIV#toggle>A#right-side {
        margin:0px auto 0px 0px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }
    DIV#toggle>A#left-side {
        margin:0px 0px 0px auto;
        background-color:#00ff00;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is an ugly mix of inline-block and float, and is very error-prone. More-over, this has the same issue as Cole Gwozdecki's answer, in that it doesn't cover the div, and won't work as soon as you put in the other content that OP has clearly described and shown in his question.

Comment: Oh I'm soo sorry to have caused you irritation. Here you go, no floats or inline blocks. Although the previous answer would have worked and was a decent illustration of a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you, sir, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yoy are very welcome, Hamza! Please make sure to accept the answer you feel is correct so that others can also find it and benefit from it.

Comment: This version, like the previous one, wouldn't cover other content in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that the buttons are in the div, you can simply position them using `position: absolute`. By adding `position: relative` to the container, you can position them within that container rather than within the document as a whole.

```css
/* -------------------------------------------------- --
   The part that you actually need
-- -------------------------------------------------- */

/* Allow elements to be positioned relative to the container */
.container {
  position: relative;
}
/* Let the buttons both cover the (left) half of the div */
.container .slidesjs-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%; /* Of .container, its positioning parent */
  height: 100%; /* Of .container */
}

/* Make an exception for the second button to move it to the right half */
.container .slidesjs-next {
  left: 50%;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------- --
   The part that's just for the demonstration.
-- -------------------------------------------------- */

/* Make the content large to show that the buttons scale */
#slides {
  padding: 50px;
}

/* Make the div red, as in the question */
.container {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Have white, semi-transparent buttons with a border, so you see where they are */
.container .slidesjs-navigation {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Make the buttons opaque on hover to show that they respond */
.container .slidesjs-navigation:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>

  <div id="slides">
    <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not good practice to overuse absolute positioning, especially that such a simple layout element could be instantiated multiple times in the document and the effect can be achieve without it! Always use the right tools for the job! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Matt. Since OP is asking to *overlay* a div *and its contents*, you would need something like this. Just making the buttons inline-block, floating them, applying flexbox or even using transforms won't solve this issue, because they keep the buttons themselves in the element flow, and will affect the size of the container div while not overlaying the other content. This is actually a perfect example of legit use of `position`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be your code.

```css
.d {
position:relative;
}
.b1 {
float:left;
height:100px;
width:75px;
}
.b2 {
position:absolute;
left:75px;
height:100px;
width:75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
<button class="b1"></button>
<button class="b2"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir could you 1+ my question

Comment: Hamza, I will surely do an up vote for you. But I will do this only when you edit your comment and remove sir from it because just like you, I am also 13 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.container {
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
background-image: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4147/5087404401_d24513119a_n.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container a{
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 50vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container a:hover{
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
 
  </div>
```

Comment: You used `49.5%` as a hack/workaround because you incorrectly used `inline-block` to solve this issue. This is very error prone, and it will actually fail if your window is small, because that space can become more than that 1% that you give it.

Comment: It is a decent solution. Neither a hack nor error prone IMHO and I've designed layouts small mobile screens. It's true that it's not the most elegant, but neither is criticizing every other poster in the thread you yourself have answered.

Comment: Matt, I have actually checked this before I commented. Just open the snippet full screen and make it small. At some point it will fail. How soon depends on various factors, including the font that the user has configured in their browser, but that's what I mean with error prone. I also casted sincere upvotes to the answers that were correct, and even praised the first correct one, which sadly was the third or fourth answer overall. I hope you can see that my comments are intended as constructive criticism, aimed to the content and not the person.

Comment: @GolezTrol I get what you mean. . I would prefer if you recommend what i should do?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Normally flexbox would solve this kind of issue, but in this case the buttons also need to overlay the other content of the container, which is why I think you need `position`, as demonstrated in the answers of me and [chriskirknielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911256/511529)

Comment: @GolezTrol will work on this kind of stuff. Thank you